# Using VBA, How to determin the Field's range in Word Document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using the code below to get the field's range. is there a way to get the Field's range without Using the Selection Object?

```vb
dim Fld as Field
dim Rng as Range
dim Prev as Range
'... Ommited code ...
set Prev=Selection.Range
fld.Select
set Rng = Selection.Range 'new selection
Prev.Select ' restore previous selection
debug.print Rng.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text
```

Comment: Have you tried looking up the documentation? E.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.fields , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.field

Comment: @TimothyRylatt, yes I did, but Field do not have Property Range. but has Select Method

Comment: But it does have a [Result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.field.result)

Comment: @TimothyRylatt, Ohh, Many thanks. can you post it as answer? I will then accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you can find the field you want you can use its [`Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.field.result) property to get the range.